# How to add static content expiration using htaccess file

Tags: php, codeigniter

htaccess file content. I want to set expiration of my static contents like images, js, css

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My images location is

```
www.sitename.com/css/css/css files
www.sitename.com/images/img/images
```

like this

Comment: Did you check http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5265/how-do-i-set-expiration-headers-for-css-js-and-images

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
<Directory "css/">
    ExpiresDefault A0
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0,  no-cache, must-revalidate"
</Directory>
```

Where `0` is the time it expires in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Check [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) documentation.

You can use something like

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
ExpiresDefault "access plus 12 hours"
</FilesMatch>
```